# How do I update the redux state without running into errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I need to update my redux store when I use certain methods. I am able to render my dummy data in my component when I mount and call the `updateCartList()` but when I try to update using the `componentDidUpdate()` and call the `updateCartInfo()` for updating the cart I get an error `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

**Edited: Added full component and actions**

Here's the dummy data `dataList`

```
export const dataList = [
    {
        id: '1',
        image: '/rice.jpg',
        price: 32,
        product: 'Yellow Corn',
        quantity: 2,
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        image: '/rice.jpg',
        price: 400,
        product: 'Beans',
        quantity: 5,
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        image: '/rice.jpg',
        price: 32,
        product: 'Banana',
        quantity: 1,
    },
];
```

The component reducers

```
const initialState = {
    cart: new Map(),
};

/**
 * Creates a Javascript Map with the cart's items mapped by id
 *
 * @param {Array} cartData - a cart item
 * @return {Map} - the new cart data list
 */

function generateCartsMap(dataList) {
    const cartData = new Map();

    dataList.forEach(list => {
        const { id } = list;
        cartData.set(id, list);
    });

    return cartData;
}

/**
 * Updates the data in the cart list
 *
 * @param {Object} cartItem - the cart item to be updated
 * @param {Map} list - the list of producer products
 * @return {Map} - the updated dataSource
 */
function updateCartInfo(cartItem, list) {
    const { id } = cartItem;
    const newList = new Map([...list.entries()]);

    newList.set(id, cartItem);

    return newList;
}

export default (state = { ...initialState }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_CART_LIST: {
            const { payload } = action;
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: generateCartsMap(payload),
            };
        }

        case UPDATE_CART_INFO: {
            const { payload } = action;
            const { cart } = state;

            return {
                ...state,
                cart: updateCartInfo(payload, cart),
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

The internal app state and methods

```
    class Cart extends Component {
    state = {
        dataList: dataList,
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        const { updateCartList } = this.props.actions;
        const { dataList } = this.state;
        updateCartList(dataList);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProp) {
        const { cart: newList } = this.props;
        const { cart: oldList } = prevProp;

        if (newList != oldList) {
            const { updateCartInfo } = this.props.actions;
            updateCartInfo();
        }
    }

    handleRemove = item => {
        const { cart } = this.props;
        const defaultCart = [...cart.values()];

        const newCart = defaultCart.filter(({ id }) => id !== item.id);
        this.setState({
            dataList: newCart,
        });
    };

    handleQuantityChange = (row, action) => {
        const { cart } = this.props;
        const values = [...cart.values()];
        const index = values.findIndex(item => row.id === item.id);
        if (action === 'add') {
            values[index] = {
                ...values[index],
                quantity: values[index].quantity + 1,
            };
        } else {
            values[index] = {
                ...values[index],
                quantity:
                    values[index].quantity > 1
                        ? values[index].quantity - 1
                        : values[index].quantity,
            };
        }
        this.setState({
            dataList: values,
        });
    };

    handleClearCart = () => {
        const cart = [];
        this.setState({
            dataList: cart,
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { cart } = this.props;
        const values = [...cart.values()];

        return (
            <div className="cart-page">
                <div className="cart-top">
                    <h2 className="cart-heading">
                        {`Cart`}
                        <Badge
                            count={values.length}
                            // title={}
                            style={{ backgroundColor: '#001529' }}
                        />
                    </h2>

                    <Popconfirm
                        className="cart-clear"
                        title="Are you sure you want to remove item?"
                        onConfirm={() => this.handleClearCart()}
                    >
                        <Button type="danger">{'Clear Cart'}</Button>
                    </Popconfirm>
                </div>

                <div className="cart-top">
                    <AppLink key={MARKET} to={MARKET}>
                        <Button className="cart-heading">{`Continue Shopping`}</Button>
                    </AppLink>
                    <AppLink key={'checkout'} to={'./'}>
                        <Button className="cart-checkout">{'Checkout'}</Button>
                    </AppLink>
                </div>

                <Table
                    className="cart-table"
                    columns={[
                        {
                            className: 'cart-table',
                            dataIndex: 'product',
                            key: 'product',
                            render: (text, record) => (
                                <div className="product-display">
                                    <img src={record.image} />
                                    <p>{record.product}</p>
                                </div>
                            ),
                            title: 'Product',
                            width: '25%',
                        },
                        {
                            className: 'cart-table',
                            dataIndex: 'price',
                            key: 'price',
                            title: 'Price',
                        },
                        {
                            className: 'cart-table',
                            dataIndex: 'quantity',
                            key: 'quantity',
                            render: (text, record) => (
                                <div className="quantity-container">
                                    <div className="quantity-value">{record.quantity}</div>
                                    <div className="quantity-actions">
                                        <Icon
                                            type="caret-up"
                                            title="Add"
                                            onClick={() => this.handleQuantityChange(record, 'add')}
                                        />
                                        <Icon
                                            type="caret-down"
                                            title="Reduce"
                                            onClick={() => this.handleQuantityChange(record, 'sub')}
                                        />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ),
                            title: 'Quantity',
                        },
                        {
                            className: 'cart-table',
                            dataIndex: 'amount',
                            key: 'amount',
                            render: (text, record) => `${record.price * record.quantity}`,
                            title: 'Amount',
                        },
                        {
                            className: 'cart-table',
                            key: 'action',
                            render: (text, record) => (
                                <Popconfirm
                                    title="Are you sure you want to remove item?"
                                    onConfirm={() => this.handleRemove(record)}
                                >
                                    <a href="javascript:;" className="danger">{`Remove`}</a>
                                </Popconfirm>
                            ),
                            title: 'Action',
                        },
                    ]}
                    dataSource={values}
                    rowKey={record => record.id}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    cart: getCart(state),
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch),
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(Cart);
```

actions.js

```
import { UPDATE_CART_INFO, UPDATE_CART_LIST } from './actionTypes';

/**
 * Triggers request to update cart items
 *
 * @function
 * @param {Object} payload An object of cart dataSource
 * @return {void} The {@link actionTypes.UPDATE_CART_LIST UPDATE_CART_LIST} action.
 */
export const updateCartList = payload => ({
    payload,
    type: UPDATE_CART_LIST,
});

/**
 * Triggers request to update cart details
 *
 * @function
 * @param {Object} payload An object of captured cart details
 * @return {void} The {@link actionTypes.UPDATE_CART_INFO UPDATE_CART_INFO} action.
 */
export const updateCartInfo = payload => ({
    payload,
    type: UPDATE_CART_INFO,
});
```

selector

```
import { NAME } from './constants';

/**
 * Selects the <tt>user</tt> key.
 *
 * @function
 * @param {Object} state - redux store state
 * @return {Number} the state data of the signin which contains user data
 * {@link module:cart/constants::INITIAL_STATE constants::INITIAL_STATE}).
 */
export const getCart = state => state[NAME].cart;
```

Comment: When you call UpdateCartInfo form inside your ComponentDidUpdate method, you're not passing in any parameters... But the method in the reducer is expecting 2. Since you pulled it from this.props.actions, i'm assuming you have a mapDispatchToProp or an ActionsCreator somewhere... are you passing the payload over correctly?

Comment: Yes I have a mapDispatchToProp I am just not sure exactly what to pass into `UpdateCartInfo`

Comment: Can we see your action UPDATE_CART_LIST, and your mapDispatchToProps.

Comment: I just updated all the code in the component.

Answer (score 1):

`updateCartInfo(cartItem, list)` takes two arguments: `cartItem` and `list`.
The first thing it does is try to deconstruct the `cartItem` and fetch the `id` property from it.

However, here you call the function with no arguments:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProp) {
  const { cart: newList } = this.props;
  const { cart: oldList } = prevProp;

  if (newList != oldList) {
    const { updateCartInfo } = this.props.actions;
    updateCartInfo(); // <------------ HERE
  }
}
```

So there is `cartItem` is `undefined` and javascript cannot read the property `id` of `undefined`.

---

### **Possible fix:**

```
function updateCartInfo(cartItem, list) {
  if(cartItem && list){
    const { id } = cartItem;
    const newList = new Map([...list.entries()]);
    newList.set(id, cartItem);
    return newList;
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

try this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProp) {
  const { cart: newList } = this.props;
  const { cart: oldList } = prevProp;

  if (newList != oldList) {
    const { updateCartInfo } = this.props.actions;
    updateCartInfo(null, newList); // <------------ HERE
  }
}
```

and:

```
function updateCartInfo(cartItem, list) {
  if(cartItem && list){
    const { id } = cartItem;
    const newList = new Map([...list.entries()]);
    newList.set(id, cartItem);
    return newList;
  } else if (list) {  // <----- HERE
    return list;      // <----- HERE
  }
}
```

---

Other than that you can also reconsider why are you invoking the `updateCartList()` function with no arguments and adjust your code logic to fit better with that. But that's beyond the scope of a stack overflow question in my opinion.

Comment: Now error says `Cannot read property 'values' of undefined`. The `values` under the render.